# how drools endless loop in one rule?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-planner

I use drools to do some logic, the DRL is like that. My question is like that when I add "rules:Rules()", the loop will loop in "young" first until age larger than 19, but if I remove "rules:Rules()", it will only do once in young. Can someone tell me why?

```
rule "young"
when
   rules:Rules() 
   person:Person(Person.age< 19) 
then
    person.age+=1
    System.out.println("young"); 
end

rule "adult"
when
   rules:Rules() 
   person:Person(Person.age>= 19) 
then
    person.age+=1
    System.out.println("adult"); 
end
```

Comment: How many `Rules` do you have in your session? Is that the real RHS of your rules? I don't see how they could cause a loop given that you are not using `modify` nor `update`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `modify` to let Drools know you are changing the state of the `person`.

```
rule "young-without-rules"
when
   $person: Person(age < 19) 
then
    modify ($person) {
       age = age+1
    }
    System.out.println("young"); 
end
```